# How to modify a link defined by an argument in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, url, jinja2

I want to modify a link according to it's ID in javascript. The problem is that I generate a list using Jinja2 so here is my code :

```
{% with ips = ips %}
{% for include in ips.includedip %}
    <div class="well form-inline">
        {{include}}
        <span class="pull-right">
        <select onchange="updateButton({{loop.index0}})" id='sel{{loop.index0}}'>
            <option>x</option>
            <option>y</option>
        </select>
        <a id="btn{{loop.index0}} "class="btn" href="/scenarios/_addObject?id={{loop.index0}}&cmd='None'"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a>
        </span>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

So here I have a list of Included IPs and I want to attribute something to one of them so I added a select in front of each one. I want then to modify the link of the button next to the select on each change. So I created a function. As the list is dynamic, I can never know how big will be the ID so here is my function :

```
function updateButton(value1){
    $('#btn$(value1)').attr('href', '#'); 
  }
```

As you can see, I pass the argument {{loop.index0}} which is interpred by jinja2 as an integer. (The first ip-select-button will have the value '0', the next one will have '1')
How can I modify the href value of the button ?
 `$('#btn$(value1)')` doesn't work and `$('#btn'+$(value1))` neither... Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost in your plate

in this function   updateButton(value1), value 1 is the loop index you want. So just use it like this

```
function updateButton(value1){
    $('#btn' + value1).attr('href', '#');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I was lost :)

Comment: No problem @Depado we are here to help each other. Happy Coding Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
$('#btn' + value1).attr('href', '#');
```